# Any way to Make pdf as image while Using Command + P

Tags: css, pdf, printing, media

is there any way to do this things?

i have an html and php page
now i'm pressing command+p for print that page and save as pdf

but i dont want to download that pdf as text selectable and editable.

how should do with css and html?

Comment: You can [encrypt the PDF](https://setapp.com/how-to/make-pdf-non-editable) as a second step after creating it.

Comment: Or you can just take a screenshot of a webpage. Some browsers and browser extensions offer the ability to create a [long screenshot](https://www.technewstoday.com/save-webpage-as-image/), which includes all of the scroll right to the bottom of the page.

Comment: @brett-donald  yur suggestion is cool its working. thanks